# Chrome Extension Oddity with Tab API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome Extension and am having some difficulty getting more than 5 tabs open. here is the source code.

## manifset.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Test",
  "description": "testing this",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "bookmarks"
  ]
}
```

## popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width: 357px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }

    </style>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

## popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function (stuff){
    traverseBookmarks(stuff[0].children[0].children);
  });
});

  function traverseBookmarks(bookmarkTreeNodes) {
    for(var i=0;i<bookmarkTreeNodes.length;i++) {
      var bookmark = document.createElement('a');

      if(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].url){
        bookmark.href = bookmarkTreeNodes[i].url;
        bookmark.target = "_blank";
      }
      else{
        (function(num) {
          bookmark.addEventListener("click", function() {
            addChildren(bookmarkTreeNodes[num].children, false );
          })})(i);
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      }
      bookmark.innerHTML = bookmarkTreeNodes[i].title;
      document.body.appendChild(bookmark);
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

      if(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].children) {
        traverseBookmarks(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].children);
      }
    }
  }

  function addChildren(children) {
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
      // will open each link in the current window
      chrome.tabs.create({
        url: children[i].url
      });
    }
  }
```

The goal is to be able to click the folder(now just a link symbolizing the folder) and open all links inside that folder. Currently what happens in I click on the link to the folder and it opens the first 5. For the sake of getting some form of logging I added:

```
var bookmark = document.createElement('a');
bookmark.innerHTML = children[i].title;
document.body.appendChild(bookmark);
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

to the addChildren() function. It prints out every child. The issue I'm running into is that when I click on the folder it only opens up the first 5 tabs then I'm guessing the focus leaves the popup so it doesn't finish. I can't really find anything else online to help

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is just as you said, when you create a new tab it is `active` by default so the popup loses focus and unloads. You could fix this in one of two ways. You can send the list of url's to a background page and have that open them all. This will work because the background page stays loaded when opening tabs.

Another, probably better, way to fix it would be to create the tabs with the `active` property set to false and then maybe switch to the first tab in the group after they are all open. Code:

```
function addChildren(children) {
  for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: children[i].url,
      active: false
    });
  }
  // switch focus to first opened tab
  chrome.tabs.query({url:children[0].url},function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[tabs.length-1].id,{active:true});
  });
}
```

Comment: Yea that was exactly it. I hate it when the answer is so obvious and you can't quite grasp it. Thank you so much!