# Simple Chrome extension doesn't always work...only when not debugging?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a very simple Chrome extension that has a popup with a single button. When you click the button, it creates a new tab, then changes the badge text in the `tabs.create` callback function. When I debug it (have the inspector window open), it works every time. However, when I use it normally (no inspector), it only works sometimes, and usually not the first one or two times. Specifically, the part that doesn't always work is the badge text part. A new tab always gets created, but the badge text is troublesome.

Does it have to do with timing? These asynchronous functions have messed with my head plenty of times. Needless to say, I want it to work every time, not just sometimes.

Here is a very simple version of my code to illustrate the basic problem that I am having:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/icon19.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<script src="background.js"></script>

<html>
<body>

<button id="start">Start</button>

</body>
</html>
```

background.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var startButton = document.getElementById('start');
    startButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        start();
    });
});


function start()
{
    // Make new tab
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: "http://google.com" }, function(tab){

        // Get random number to display in badge to test if it's working
        var randomString = String(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));

        // Display badge
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: randomString});

    });
}
```

Comment: It works just fine for me. One question I have is why you have the same script running as a background script as well as being in your popup page. It still works even though it causes it to throw an error, but it doesn't do anything being in the background page.

Comment: You're right about the background page. I took it out of the manifest and it still runs. But even then, it still doesn't work for me all the time. Sometimes it just doesn't add the badge text. I would debug it, but it always works when debugging (because the popup stays open, maybe?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741485/chrome-extension-oddity-with-tab-api) where the popup would unload before all of the code executed. I personally have not had it not update but I can imagine that it is possible. One way to fix this would be to not let the popup unload until it is done executing the call back. The key to this is the `active` property of `tabs.create`. Example:

```
function start(){
  // Make new tab
  chrome.tabs.create({ url:"http://google.com", active:false }, function(tab){

    // Get random number to display in badge to test if it's working
    var randomString = String(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));

    // Display badge
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: randomString});

    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id,{active:true});
  });
}
```

Doing it like this should eliminate the race condition and ensure the popup keeps focus until it sets the badge.

Comment: Perfect! It works great. I hadn't even explored the active property yet. Thanks for the very quick help.

Comment: I've spent some time figuring out why do my tabs are randomly activated at startup. The key was `active: true` part of this answer. The real answer is that you cannot set badge on a page if it's not active. You should listen for `onActivated` event.